# How to collect real time data from SENSORTAG and store it in mongo db as json object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sensors

I am trying to get data from CC260 TI sensor tag api. I am getting the data but its not in sequence. sometimes I get only temp at once and then humidity ,next luxometer reading. The pattern of emitting the data is abnormal.I know that sensor might by emitting the data from all its data points at once, so want to get data in that form which is been emitted by sensor. I am using node.js and want to store data in mongodb.

ex : I am getting the data like this

```
temp:10
temp:10
temp:10
pressure:3
pressure:4
humity:5
pressure:5
humidity:4
temp:10
```

I know that the reason might be because of asynchronism behaviour of node.js.My question is how to control the stream of data, make a Json string like the one which I mentioned below

but I want it like this

```
{ 
temp:10
pressure:2
humidity:2
luxometer:3
}
{temp:18
pressure:4
humidity:3
luxometer:1
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have any logic to find which temp value correspond to which pressure value or something like how those values will be clubbed , how they correspond to each other ? or is it like , 1st temp correspond to 1st pressure and to 1st humidity and 1st luxometer and 2nd temp for 2nd pressure ... so on ?

Comment: Thnx for the reply. I do have the logic for finding temperature , pressure nd humidity repevtively. Thrs no order for it. I get it like tag.notify( Temp) will gve me temp similatly others. @aishwat

Comment: Thnx for the reply .yea i do have the logic for get temperature, pressure, humidity values respectively. Like i have a method which  notifies me temp like tag. On ( ' temp') gives me tempetature , tag.on(' pressure') gives me pressure respevtively.but becus of async, i m not able to control stream.